# Origin of the term “physical density parameter” for $\omega_i = \Omega_i h^2$

Tags: cosmology, terminology

When measuring cosmological density parameters, the parameters that are actually determined are the combinations $\Omega_i h^2$, sometimes defined as $\omega_i = \Omega_i h^2$, rather than the “plain” density parameters $\Omega_i = \rho_{i, 0} / \rho_{\mathrm{crit}, 0}$, so I understand the relevance of $\omega_i$.
However, $\omega_i$ are often called the “physical densities”, and I don’t understand why that is (is there something “un-physical” about $\Omega_i$)?
Unfortunately, I haven’t been able to find an explanation of this term “physical densities” anywhere – it always just seems to be taken for granted.
What is “physical” supposed to mean in this context?

Examples of using the term “physical densities” for $\omega_i$:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#cite_note-physical_density-88
- https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept03/Peacock/Peacock8.html
- https://cmb.wintherscoming.no/equations.php
- https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/education/graphic_history/parameters.html
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5226 (WMAP)
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1389
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209 (Planck)
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.08277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing "unphysical" about $\Omega_i$. From a purely theoretical perspective, $\Omega_i$ is arguably a more natural quantity than $\omega_i$. However, the value of $\Omega_i$ depends on the Hubble constant $H_0$, which is not known very precisely. Therefore it is often useful to quote observational results in terms of $\omega_i=\Omega_i h^2$ instead of $\Omega_i$, where $H_0=100h\ {\rm km\ s^{-1}\ {Mpc}^{-1}}$. The reason is that $\omega_i$ does not depend on the value of the Hubble constant. The observational uncertainty for $\omega_i$ is therefore much less than the uncertainty for $\Omega_i$.

It is similar to the idea that the mass of the Earth $M_\oplus$ is only known to five or so decimal places, but $GM_\oplus$ is known to *much* better precision (ten or so), because $G$ is not known very precisely and $GM_\oplus$ is the quantity that is actually measured.

---

Under Eq 2, the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08991 says "The dimensionless quantity $\omega_x \equiv \Omega_x h^2$ is proportional to the physical density of component $x$ at the present day." This suggests the following as a possible interpretation of the term "physical density parameter": the physical density $\rho_x$ is given by
$$
\rho_x = \frac{3 H_{100}^2 c^2 \omega_x}{8 \pi G},
$$
where $H_{100} \equiv 100\ {\rm km s^{−1} Mpc^{−1}}$. Since all quantities on the right hand side are known to good precision, so is $\rho_x$. If you used $H_0$ instead of $H_{100}$ and $\Omega_x$ instead of $\omega_x$, you would introduce uncertainty into $\rho_x$.

Comment: +1 Good analogy re: $GM$ accuracy/measure compared to $G$ and $M$ seperate. Also,  $M_\odot$ represents the sun's mass and usually $M_\oplus$ that for earth? Just nitpicking.

Comment: @josephh Of course you are right, thank you! I'll fix that.

Comment: No problems Andrew. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, this is what I understood. I’m mostly confused about the term “physical”, since it doesn’t really seem like an appropriate term to describe this difference (to go with your analogy, we don’t call $GM_\oplus$ the “physical mass of the Earth”). But if you’re saying that this is all there is to it, I can live with that.

Comment: @Socob To be completely up front, I've never heard anyone use the term "physical" for this quantity, so it's possible they have something specific in mind that I'm not aware of. But, I don't see how introducing $h$ could be part of a "physically natural" quantity, given that its value depends on an arbitrary reference scale of $100\ {\rm km\ s^{-1}\ Mpc^{-1}}.$

Comment: @Andrew Might just be another piece of jargon then… I do hope someone more familiar with this wording chimes in as well!

Comment: @Socob Under Eq 2, the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08991 says "The dimensionless quantity $\omega_x \equiv \Omega_x h^2$ is proportional to the physical density of component $x$ at the present day." This could lead to the following interpretation of the term "physical density parameter": the physical density $\rho_x$ is given by $\rho_x = \omega_x \frac{3 H_{100}^2 c^2}{3\pi G}$, where $H_{100}=100\ {\rm km\ s^{-1}\ Mpc^{-1}}$. Since all quantities on the RHS are known to good precision, so is $\rho_x$. If you used $H_0$ instead of $H_{100}$, you would introduce uncertainty into $\rho_x$.

Comment: (Of course if you use $H_0$ instead of $H_{100}$, you also need to use $\Omega_x$ instead of $\omega_x$.)

Comment: @Andrew Ah, that’s a very good point! I think that makes the most sense to me, that $\omega_i$ is a “physical density parameter” because it is like $\rho_i$ (just with constants applied to make it dimensionless, where these constants are more “fundamental” and not part of the same set being measured in observational cosmology). Looking at it again, I think @seVenVo1d’s answer pretty much says the same thing, but it was worded in a way where it didn’t “click” for me :-D

I think it would be clearest if there were a version $\omega_i(t)$, which would scale the same way as $\rho$ with $a(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to contribute to @Andrew's answer.

As we know $$\Omega_{\rm i} \equiv \frac{\rho_{\rm i}}{\rho_{\rm c}}$$ where $\rho_{\rm c} = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$. Thus the physical density parameter becomes

$$\omega_{\rm i} = \Omega_{\rm i}h^2 = \rho_{\rm i}\frac{8\pi G}{3H^2}\frac{H^2}{10^4}=c\rho_i$$ where $c$ is some constant. Thus, unlike $\Omega_{\rm i}$, $\omega_{\rm i}$ does not contain $H_0$ and thus it's model independent.

To give you an example, consider $\omega_{\rm r}$ parameter

$$\omega_{\rm r} = 2.469 \times 10^{-5} \times [1 + \frac{7}{8} (\frac{4}{11})^{4/3}N_{\rm eff}]$$ This parameter only depends on the $N_{\rm eff}$ and $T_{\rm CMB}$. So if your cosmological model does not change these parameters then $\omega_{\rm r}$ will be constant. However, depending  on the $H_0$, $\Omega_{\rm r}$ will be different.

For instance, most cosmological models do not change $\omega_{\rm r}$. So, if your new cosmological model predicts different $H_0$ (and does not change $N_{\rm eff}$), you’ll have different $\Omega_{\rm r,0}$ but same $\omega_{\rm r}$.

Comment: Well, this is all very reasonable, but as I was trying to say in the comments, it’s still not clear to me why one would call this “physical density”. With your explanation, I could see it being called “model-independent density” or something similar, but not “physical”.